# Nested forms using the Cocoon gem in Ruby on Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4.2, cocoon-gem

I'm building a web app using Rails 4.2 and I have a model called Strategy which has a has_many relationship to a Tactic model.

To create a view for Strategy, I need to have many nested Tactics on the form.  I've been using the Cocoon gem to develop this view.

So far, I've been able to get the form to work properly for the most part but the issue is that I wanted to add a Type attribute to my Tactic model.

For a given strategy, I want to have 3 tactics of one given type, and 2 models of another.

The issue is that rendering my view, all five models are listed sequentially without any room for putting in my own HTML code around them.

Is there a simple way to separate out which of these are rendered?  Right now, my view looks as follows...

```
<%= form_for @strategy do |f| %>
    <div class="strategy">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="tactics">
        <%= f.fields_for :tactics do |i| %>
            <%= render 'tactics_fields', f: i %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <%= f.button "Save Strategy", class: 'button' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

If anyone can offer any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the form to be rendered so that each Strategy has exactly 5 Tactics listed below it, of which 3 are of one type and 2 are of another?

If so, you can do this in your controller:

```
5.times do
  tactic = @strategy.tactics.build
  tactic.tactic_type = 'tactic_type'
end
```

Also, note that using an attribute called `type` is not a good idea. Use something like `tactic_type` instead.

Comment: Not quite.  I already have 5x @strategy.tactics.build in my controller, which is working well.

The issue is that when I am trying to implement the five nested 'tactics' forms in the view, they are all put in using the partial view helper.  I am just looking to have each of them rendered one at a time, so that I can put other HTML elements around some of the nested forms.

Comment: So just render a different partial depending on what kind of tactic it is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a bit confused.  To try to clear up where I am running into trouble, its the content in the code sample above wrapped within the `<div class="tactics">` section.

At present, it just renders all five nested forms in a row.  What I'd like to be able to do is render just one of them, or just two, for example, and then do some custom HTML before rendering out the rest.

Am I overlooking something simple?